# Safe place for file downloads on WordPress

Tags: wordpress, security, download, server

I'm working on a portfolio website by using WordPress and I want to include file downloads for my Resume and Design Process documents. Where is it safe to put my file downloads so others can download them with a link?

Is it safe to put the files on the same server or would that be a security risk?

Answer (score 1):

A link to a document is the same as a link to an image or anything else static. It does not introduce a security risk, as a visitor can do nothing with it except download the document, which I assume is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can either create a special folder for it under your /public_html/ and then upload it via FTP, or alternatively simply upload it via the Media -> Add New.

Once it is uploaded, open it in Media Library to get the permanent link to it. 
As [bobdye](https://stackoverflow.com/users/488187/bobdye)
pointed out, there is no security risk with static documents.

Comment: The requirement wasn't that it was available via Wordpress, just that it is downloadable 'with a link' hence the FTP option in my answer.

Comment: Only if they somehow confused FTW with Wordpress, seeing as those are the two options in my answer.